# MPMoviePlayerController issue of thumbnail when video taken in landscape mode

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am working with creating thumbnail using MPMoviePlayerController . I am using following code :

```
  MPMoviePlayerController *controller = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
  UIImage *image = [controller thumbnailImageAtTime:5 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
```

it is working fine when I am recording the video in portrait mode . But the problem occurs when video is recorded in landscape mode . It is giving me the 90 degree rotated image as it was in thumbnail . How can I get proper thumbnail for landscape image ?

Comment: @NainaSoni: actually I solved this by rotating image explicitly when it is taken in landscape mode